# Eclipse - CTRL+Space autocompletion does not work any more for Java

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

In my Eclipse workspace, CTRL+Space does not provide any suggestions since a while. The suggestion popup appears but stays empty. Toggling between *default proposals* and others like *Template proposals* does not help.

It started some days ago with an error message which I unfortunately clicked away too quickly. I've tried already to start Eclipse with `-clean` option which did not help.

My Eclipse version is 2020-06 (4.16.0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Preferences » Java » Editor » Content Assist » Advanced.
Make sure Other Java Proposals is ticked/checked

Comment: Wow, that was simple. I wonder who unchecked it. Thanks

Comment: That happened to me after installing a new eclipse version.