# Eclipse - Ctrl+Space Content Assist doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, settings, autosuggest

I have just installed the 2020-12 version of Eclipse IDE, and I simply cannot get the Ctrl+Space suggestions to work. Every time I try to use them I get an empty suggestion box.

I've already searched for this of course, and I've found many who suggest how to fix it.

- https://superuser.com/questions/209752/eclipse-doesnt-autocomplete-and-find-references-anymore
- [Eclipse - CTRL+Space autocompletion does not work any more for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63592813/eclipse-ctrlspace-autocompletion-does-not-work-any-more-for-java)
- https://mkyong.com/java/content-assist-ctrl-space-is-not-working-eclipse/
- [No Default Proposals in Eclipse Juno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653448/no-default-proposals-in-eclipse-juno)
- [Eclipse/Java code completion not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908489/eclipse-java-code-completion-not-working)

Most of these say I need the *Other Java Proposals* in the settings, but if you look at the image you see that that option doesn't even exist! In the image the *default settings* are applied but I've also tried to check every single one of those boxes and still get an empty suggestion box when I press Ctrl+Space at the end of Combi (also in the image).

Image of the issue and my settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYdaG.jpg

Comment: Are there any other errors in the project?

Comment: Please show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (reproducible with the default settings). In the screenshot I see the file `Combi.java` that can or cannot contain the type `Combi` (it might also contain a non-public other type). It is also unclear whether code completion proposals are not shown only at this specific location or in general.

Comment: @howlger In this case, the Combi.java file you see is the type Combi, it has a single public constructor that takes two arguments of type JCheckBox and simply assigns them to two public final variables for future access. The code suggestion I want when pressing Ctrl+Space is to add 'iim3.data.Combi' to the imports at the top. And the code completion proposal box is empty regardless of where I try. There are no errors in the whole workspace except for this single one at the moment.

Comment: Please show a minimal reproducible example (reproducible with the default settings).

Comment: @howlger I don't quite understand how to produce a minimal reproducible example, since so many things can affect it, but here's exactly what I did; I went to eclipse.org and downloaded the "Eclipse IDE 2020‑12 x86_64" as a zip. I extracted it, started it, and then selected my previous workspace after deleting the ".metadata" folder and imported the projects. Then I opened a java class in an existing project, started writing a new line, and immediately found that Ctrl+Space only even opens empty suggestion boxes. Does that help?

Comment: Never ever delete the `.metadata` folder. That's a hoax spread on Stack Overflow that can cause damage. If possible restore it (hopefully you have made a backup), otherwise create a new workspace and import your project from the damaged workspace.